# Python - save API responses to csv file in a for loop

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to scrape lyrics from an api and print responses directly to a `csv` file, like so:

```
def scrape_genius_lyrics(urls):

    all_lyrics=[]

    headers = {'Authorization': 'mytoken'}
    base_url = 'https://genius.com/'

    with codecs.open('genius.csv', 'ab', encoding='utf8') as outputfile:
        outwriter = csv.writer(outputfile)

    for url in urls:
        page_url = base_url + url
        try:
            page = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
            html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
            [h.extract() for h in html('script')]
            lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()         
            # outwriter.writerow(lyrics)
            all_lyrics.append(lyrics)
            print lyrics
        except:
            'could not find page for {}'.format(url)
```

however, I only see responses if i comment `#outwriter.writerow(lyrics)`, otherwise the program halts and does not print lyrics.

how can I save to `csv` file every lyrics to its own row, at each iteration?

Comment: `[h.extract() for h in html('script')]` on it's own does nothing... Did you want to save that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should indent that for loop to keep the writer open.

```
with codecs.open('genius.csv', 'ab', encoding='utf8') as outputfile:
    outwriter = csv.writer(outputfile)

    for url in urls:
        page_url = base_url + url
        ...
```

You also should decide if you really need to store `all_lyrics` in memory while you write the same information to the file.

You can always re-open the file and get `all_lyrics` at a later point.